# How do I create an exe file of gui made using pyqt5?(There are several ui files)

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I tried to create an exe file.

I have several ui files, of which I tried to make user_view_ui.py, which acts as a main_window, an executable file.

Step 1)
user_view_ui.py

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

form_ui = uic.loadUiType("ui\\user_view.ui")[0]

class UserViewUi(QMainWindow, form_ui):
...
```

And, I added the "resource_path" function in the others python files.

Step2) I modified user_view_ui.spec file.

```
ui_list = ['.\\ui\\user_view.ui', '.\\ui\\change_list_view.ui', '.\\ui\\move_to_another_changelist.ui', '.\\ui\\login.ui', '.\\ui\\user_settings.ui']

a = Analysis(['user_view_ui.py'],
             pathex=[],
             binaries=[],
             datas=ui_list,
```

but, when I execute the "pyinstaller --onefile user_view_ui.spec", below the errors occur.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 124, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 58, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 803, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 725, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "user_view_ui.spec", line 20, in <module>
    noarchive=False)
  File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 287, in __init__
    for name, pth in format_binaries_and_datas(datas, workingdir=spec_dir):
  File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 506, in format_binaries_and_datas
    for src_root_path_or_glob, trg_root_dir in binaries_or_datas:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .spec file the datas field expects a list of tuples containing the path to data file and the target folder it should be copied into at execution time.

for example:

```
ui_list = [
('.\\ui\\user_view.ui','.\\ui'), 
('.\\ui\\change_list_view.ui','.\\ui'), 
('.\\ui\\move_to_another_changelist.ui','.\\ui'),
('.\\ui\\login.ui', '.\\ui'),
('.\\ui\\user_settings.ui','.\\ui')
]

a = Analysis(['user_view_ui.py'],
             pathex=[],
             binaries=[],
             datas=ui_list,
```

You can try using relative paths in your resource function.

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    base_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    uipath = os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
    return os.path.relpath(uipath, '.')

form_ui = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(resource_path("ui"),"user_view.ui"))[0]
```

Comment: After updating as you told me, other error occurs.

"File "user_view_ui.spec", line 11, in <module>
    ('.\\ui\\user_settings.ui', '.\\ui')
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable"

Comment: @seonguk.jeon  Sorry I left out a comma.... Try it now

Comment: no problem! I also didn't check it properly either.

Comment: Could you help me more question?

"I added the "resource_path" function in the others python files.(except main.py)"

Is it right?

Comment: @seonguk.jeon I am not really sure what that means, but I provided a function similar in my answer